# Classification according to hierarchical rules with Python and SQL Server

Tags: python-3.x, classification, hierarchy, rules, sql-server-2019

**Short Summary**

I am looking for advice on solution design for classifying in Python 3.9 according to rules with hierarchical structure, as well as suggestions on how to store the rules.

---

**Detailed Description**

I have a bunch of data with similar attributes in Python, for example representing employees of some company. The actual representation may be in a dictionary or in some data-holder-like class. Possible attributes are strings (e.g. first and last name), floats (hourly wage or top tax rate), integers (days off taken this year and remaining) and dates (starting employment date, birth date).  Some could be enums as well (e.g. gender). Also, structures of these types are possible as well, e.g. a list of dates for all vacation days taken this year.

I also have a couple of rules with hierarchical relationships, which be the following:

1. field + operator + value: e.g. position == manager. Any field of the employee is valid, operator can be ==, <, <=, >=, > or basic string functions like contains/startswith/endswith/regexMatch. (e.g. last name contains "son" is ok.)
2. boolean combinations of other rules (e.g. if we define (A) last name starts with "A-K" and (B) salary > 100K, all 3 of [(A) and (B)], [not (B)] and [(A) or (B)] are ok.)
3. it may optionally be assumed at least one rule will be true on any employee in question, but it does not have to be so.

I would like to design a solution that would

1. Store the rules in SQL Server 2018 (in some manageable form).
2. Be able to read the rules form the DB and (efficiently) apply the rules to a bunch of similar employee objects, for each figuring out the first rule in the hierarchy that will match each particular employee (or that none will -- some variation is possible here due to potential assumption (3) above).

I am looking for suggestions of design and which Python libraries to use to implement this usefully.

---

**Sample Implementation 1**

One proposal I can suggest how to implement and store what I want.

- Break down each rule into fundamentals (collapsing the hierarchy) and represent it with a JSON schema with special "and"/"or"/"not" nodes.
- Store in SQL Server as a long `varchar()` but use `JSON_VALUE` and `JSON_QUERY` etc. to work with it.
- Consume into Python directly, converting a string to JSON schema
- To apply the rules, use the `Cerberus` [Python library](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/usage.html) to validate each employee holder against the schema of each rule until one of them matches.

For example, if we have records (first, last, age, salary)

- John, Doe,  43, 50000
- Alex, Meth, 65, 43000

and the rules

- **A.30.30**:  {last starts with A..K, age <= 30,      salary <= 30k}
- **A.50.30**:  {last starts with A..K, 30 < age <= 50, salary <= 30k}
- **A.70.30**:  {last starts with A..K, 50 < age,       salary <= 30k}
- **A.30.70**:  {last starts with A..K, age <= 30,      30k < salary <= 70k}
- **A.50.70**:  {last starts with A..K, 30 < age <= 50, 30k < salary <= 70k}
- **A.70.70**:  {last starts with A..K, 50 < age,       30k < salary <= 70k}
- **A.30.100**: {last starts with A..K, age <= 30,      70k < salary}
- **A.50.100**: {last starts with A..K, 30 < age <= 50, 70k < salary}
- **A.70.100**: {last starts with A..K, 50 < age,       70k < salary}
- similarly for B.?.? last will start with M..Z

Apply the rules to John Doe first:

- **A.30.30**:  last name ok, age mismatch
- **A.50.30**:  last name ok, age ok,      salary mismatch
- **A.70.30**:  last name ok, age mismatch
- **A.30.70**:  last name ok, age mismatch
- **A.50.70**:  last name ok, age ok,      salary ok

So John Doe get classified with the label **A.50.70**. Notice a huge number of extra comparisons here, since the hierarchical structure of comparisons has been ignored.

This is nice in that if the rule structure changes, we only need to change the rules hierarchy, not the code. The problems with this solution are

- application of many rules to employees is very inefficient, since the path along the first rule does not influence others which may be very much related; and
- storing rules as JSON does not sound like a great idea, since visually inspecting the data of the properties used and how exactly they are used becomes very problematic.

I would like to get suggestions for better solutions, please. I am happy to use Python libraries to deal with this easily instead of implementing myself if possible. Thank you.